# How to make collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

There is a user based on Devise system.
User_has_one: user_profile, and user_profile_belongs_to: User
User_profile_has_one: language, and language_belongs_to: User_profile

In 'user_profiles' table, there is a column called "language_id" to know what language the user speaks.
In 'languages' table, there is a column called "name". This could be like English, Spanish and language kind.

Now I wanna add language selection to my devise's edit page

It should be something like this below. right?

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

      <div><%= profile_form.label :nickname %><br /> 
      <%= profile_form.text_field :nickname %></div> 

      <div><%= profile_form.label :language_id %><br /> 
      <%= profile_form.collection_select(language_id, @languages, language_id, name_ja ) %></div> 

    <% end %> 



  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>
  <br />
  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.</p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Updated!

edit method in registrations_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @languages = Language.all
    @countries = Country.all 
    @prefectures = Prefecture.all
    @genders = Gender.all 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're assigning @languages in the controller, then you probably want something like:

```
<%= profile_form.collection_select(:language_id, @languages, :id, :name) %>
```

You want to pass symbols that represent the methods that should be called, so ":language_id" instead of "language_id"

Comment: thanks, what I changed it to that, but it still says 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass'.

Comment: Do I need to write something in my controller?? like @languages =??? or in views?

Comment: I have no edit method in my registrations_controller.rb because it calls devise everytime. But I am trying to figure out please check my update!

Comment: It's almost there!!by adding this to controller @languages = Language.select('DISTINCT name') but all the values are blank when output. Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks I tried to add them except jquery thing. but I still get this error when I try to update 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: jquery? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: sorry. my bad. ignore that part please. I tried everything what you told me to do.  But I still get this error when I update 'undefined method`map' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: You're probably having trouble with the devise controllers, that's a tricky problem. Try changing `@languages` to `Language.all` and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks!! what do you mean by changing @ languages to Language.all?? my edit method is just @ languages = Language.all now

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action you should have -

```
@languages = Language.find_by_sql("select distinct id, name from languages")
```

and in the view

```
<%= collection_select :language, :id, @languages, :id, :name %>
```

and in jquery you can access this variable using -

```
var languageId = $('select#language_id :selected').val();
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to add them except jquery thing. but I still get this error when I try to update 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass'